# Checking if date is matching date format

Tags: swift, datetime

So it is pretty straight forward code. I have an input date that I want to validate against a specific format (the input date should perfectly match the date format specified), so I used the following code, input an invalid date (that should failed matching) but to my surprise it matches the date format and returns a valid date

```
import Foundation

let inputValue = "12/10/199" // Returns valid date even for "12/10.199"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"


if let dateOfBirth = dateFormatter.date(from: inputValue) {
    print("Valid date \(dateOfBirth)") // Prints Valid date. Why?
}
else {
    print("Invalid date")
}
```

Console output

```
Valid date 0199-10-11 18:06:32 +0000
```

Comment: Because the year is padded with a zero to be four digits by the formatter, and "12/10/0199" is a valid date (all parts are padded so "7/2/199" is also valid). You need to apply some further checks to validate the date depending on what you consider a valid date.

Comment: add a extra condition to check if the date is between some dates. eg( your_date_year > 1800 or something)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ahh I get it. Thanks. One more question though. Why does it allow(or considers a valid date) a date with value "12/10.199" even tho it does not follows the dateFormat mentioned (which is dd/MM/yyyy, input value has . instead of /)

Comment: Please change the title since you’re checking a timestamp format

Comment: I am not sure why the dot works, I haven’t found any documentation about it

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the input is a timestamp not a date value, the intent is to validate a string as a date.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson well it’s not a date it’s a string. And why the date formatter should’t parse it? Because of the 3 digits for the year rather than 4?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson like I wrote in my answer this would have worked also by using “-“ as separators in the parsed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Unicode Date Format Patterns](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) only the two digit year format `yy` checks also for the length, 3 `y` and more add leading zeros up to the number of `y`.

My suggestion is to validate the string format with Regular Expression (the whole string must be *2 digits followed by a slash followed by two digits followed by a slash followed by 4 digits*) and to use the new Date[`ParseStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/parsestrategy) API introduced in iOS 15 / macOS 12 which is more comprehensible than the abstract string date format pattern.

```
let inputValue = "12/10/199"
let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(format: "\(day: .twoDigits)/\(month: .twoDigits)/\(year: .defaultDigits)",
                                  timeZone: .current)

if let _ = inputValue.range(of: #"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$"#, options: .regularExpression),
   let dateOfBirth = try? Date(inputValue, strategy: strategy) {
    print("Valid date \(dateOfBirth)")
}
else {
    print("Invalid date")
}
```

In iOS 16 / macOS 10.13 the regex validation will be included in ParseStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mistake the string you use as format of the date formatter for a regular expression.
This would have also worked if the parsed string used the “-“ as separator between the date components.